# What alternatives to httpListener exist on Mono and support SSL?

Tags: c#, .net, web-server, ssl, mono

Because of a long-standing SSL support problem with httpListener on mono, a lot of people take various workarounds to run an http server application on Mono.

One of the work arounds is to simply use an alternative listener, and that's what I'd prefer.

I found one alternative library called Ceen Httpd
https://github.com/kenkendk/ceenhttpd

It looks pretty good, but it's the only one I've found, so it doesn't leave me with any options to consider. I just want to know if there's anything else out there that someone knows about.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. For example, what feature set do you need? What options are you looking for?

Comment: I think its a pretty clear question that needs no details. An httpListener on Mono and supports SSL.  There are like barely any options at all.  If someone even knows of ONE option, they can respond with it. Ceen is the only one I've even found that looks relatively mature.